# Can't save string to Realm Swift

Tags: swift, string, realm

I'm trying to save a string to Realm. For some reason, a nil value is being saved to Realm. Here is the function where I save to Realm (imageKey is the String)

```
func saveImageKey(_ imageKey: Data){
        do{
            try realm.write{
                realm.add(imageKey)
            }
        }
        catch{
            print("Error saving imageKey: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if this affects Realm, but when initializing the imageKey variable, I used a didSet to reorganize the imageKey objects by date created as follows:

```
var imageKey: Results<Data>?{
        didSet{ //every time imageKey is updated, this will be called
            imageKey = imageKey!.sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)
            print(imageKey)
        }
    }
```

This is how I converted the imageKey string into a Data object:

```
  let newData = Data()
        newData.imageKey = "item" + String(textCount)
         saveImageKey(newData)
```

This is the class definition for Data:

```
class Data: Object{
    @objc dynamic var text: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageKey: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var date = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

}
```

I have already checked for common errors, such as not initializing Realm, not adding the `dynamic` to the variable declarations in the `Data` class.

What could the issue be? Please let me know if you need more code/information.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the logic where you convert your String into Data. (imageKey is of type Data)

Comment: @rs7 I have updated my post

Comment: I would try a couple things to debug this: 1. Add a print(imageKey) statement just before you save imageKey in realm to make sure that the object you are saving is not empty. 2. Try commenting out the didSet block and see if that helps.

Comment: What is Data? Is that your realm object? If so can you post class definition?

Comment: There's not enough info or code in the question to understand the issue. For example `let newData = Data()` and then `newData.imageKey ` - a Swift Data object does not have an `imageKey` member. So what's going on there - if you've crafted your own Data class, that would be confusing naming it the same? And why are you converting a String to a Data object and then back to a String in the first place? Just leave it as a String? As mentioned, what is that Data class? The question states **Can't save string to Realm Swift** but the imageKey is this `var imageKey: Results<Data>?`, not a string.

Comment: @Jay Data is the Realm object. I have updated my code.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting here `imageKey = imageKey!.sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)` as imageKey is a string `@objc dynamic var imageKey: String = ""` and where is this piece if code `var imageKey: Results<Data>?{`? As you can see, what's in the question is a bit disjointed so it's hard to understand what's going on.